# Which xpath will work for the html code

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have the following html code for a radio button

```
<span id="ViewModel_515" class="gwt-RadioButton WPOW WCOW WJPW WAPW" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" role="presentation" data-automation-id="radioBtn">
  <input id="gwt-uid-451" class="WLOW" type="radio" name="ViewModel_513" value="on" tabindex="0" checked="">
  <label id="ViewModel_515-label" class="WMOW" for="gwt-uid-451" data-automation-selected="true" data-automation-label="Smart Calculation Based on Events">Smart Calculation Based on Events</label>
</span>
```

And I tried to use the following xpath:

```
//label[text()='Smart Calculation Based on Events']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']
```

Which is not working.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to locate a check box and click on it.

Comment: try using `contains(text(),'Smart Calculation Based on Events')` instead of `text()='Smart Calculation Based on Events'`

Comment: how do i write the entire xpath. I Tried : //[contains(text(),'Smart Calculation']/following-sibling::input[@type='radio'] which is invalid

Comment: @dealsforyou , there is no need in `contains(text(),'Smart Calculation Based on Events')` - your XPath is correct. It might be timing issue or `iframe` or something else, but obviously not an XPath issue... Share your code along with Exception log

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//input[@class='WLOW' and starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid-') and starts-with(@name,'ViewModel_')]
```

Or you cab get more granular as follows :

```
//span[@class='gwt-RadioButton WPOW WCOW WJPW WAPW' and starts-with(@id,'ViewModel_')]/input[@class='WLOW' and starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid-') and starts-with(@name,'ViewModel_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you click on the text, the checkbox will not be selected. Try using one mentioned below.

```
//input[@type ='radio'] (or)
//input[@type ='radio' and starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid-')] 


/*If you have more than one checkbox, use value in an index as per selection */

 (//input[@type ='radio'])[index]
 (//input[@type ='radio' and starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid-')])[index]
```

For example, the page has two checkboxes and need to click on the second one.

```
(//input[@type ='radio'])[2]
(//input[@type ='radio' and starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid-')])[2]
```